# “No signal” at external display connecting to MacBook Pro using DisplayPort

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I’ll be really grateful for any recommendations in solving the problem of connecting an external monitor to *MacBook Pro* using a miniDisplayPort / DisplayPort cable.

For a long time I used *AOC I2369VM* (1080p, 60Hz) as an external monitor for *MacBook Pro (Early 2011, 13”, macOS 10.13.6)* using a miniDisplayPort / DisplayPort cable, and it’s work perfectly. A couple of days ago I bought a new *AOC I2475PXQU* (1080p, 60Hz) and it doesn’t work: the laptop “sees” the monitor and creates a second desktop, however on the monitor I see the message “No signal” only. In some cases, the laptop freezes or spontaneously reboots when the monitor is connected or disconnected. When I change the image output settings to 1080i or 720p, sometimes the second desktop appears on the monitor (but in most cases I see the message “No signal” only). For some reason, the monitor is defined as *I2475W1* in the system settings. I tried using a different cable with the same connectors, however this didn’t fix the issue. I performed a reset of NVRAM, PRAM and SMC — this didn’t help either. In addition, I performed Apple Hardware Test — there are no errors. Also, I connected other devices to this monitor using HDMI, and they worked perfectly.

**Update:** According to the monitor menu, H. Frequency is 45 KHz at 720p and 34 KHz at 1080i; V. Frequency is 60 Hz at any settings. When other devices connected by HDMI, H. Frequency is 68 KHz and V. Frequency is 60 Hz.

How can I localize and fix the issue? Can the miniDisplayPort / DVI adapter solve the problem? (I have a DVI cable.) Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tony, welcome to Ask Different. Have you had a chance to test the monitor with a different computer or cable? The miniDisplayPort / DVI adapter could definitely solve the problem, I use two such adapters at work and haven't had any problems so far.

Comment: Thank you, @jaume. I used two different cables miniDisplayPort / DisplayPort. Both cables work fine with the old monitor (I2369VM), but don’t work with the new one (I2475PXQU). Unfortunately, I have no way to test the monitor with another MacBook.

Anyway, thanks for your comment. I ordered a miniDisplayPort / DVI adapter. Let’s see how the monitor will work with it.

Comment: Ehi @TonyGotHisGun , I have exactly your same problem with this monitor `i2475PXQU`. With HDMI cable it doesn't work, but with VGA cable all works fine. Windows works perfectly with the same HDMI cable. It's weired. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

most probable cause is the mDP cable
different cable / adapter should solve the problem

Comment: Thank you, @Hardijs. I used two different cables miniDisplayPort / DisplayPort. Both cables work fine with the old monitor (I2369VM), but don’t work with the new one (I2475PXQU). I ordered a miniDisplayPort / DVI adapter. Let’s see how the monitor will work with it.